# UI changes now I have no clue how to find my stuff

Tags: azure-devops

I'll preface this by saying that I'm fairly new to VSTS.

I'm not sure how this happened but the UI changed for only me on my tream's instance of VSTS (now Azure DevOps). I now have no clue how to get to any our user stories sprints, current work, etc.

I see a bunch of pretty logos on the left for things that have to do with out configuration (Repros, Artifacts, etc.)

I cannot find a way to see all work items as the filters only show for Recently updated, completed or created. *(What defines "recently"?)

Is thee a way to revert the UI back to what it was and why am I the only one on my team with the new look?

Oh and all of the emails sent announcing the new name change (along with assigned work) were blocked by our company's spam filter as they started coming from a new email address.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! Under the avatar (upper right) go to "Preview features" and turn everything OFF.